# App crashes if app is closed using Push service: parse.com

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, push

I replace receiver in manifest to mine:

```
<receiver android:name="com.myparse.app.MyReceiver"
    android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
    <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

This is my MyReceiver:

```
public class MyReceiver extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    protected void onPushReceive(Context mContext, Intent intent) {
//      super.onPushReceive(arg0, arg1);

        if (intent.hasExtra("com.parse.Data")){
            String jsonString=intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");
            //-------------
    }

   public void onPushOpen(Context context, Intent intent) {

        //To track "App Opens"
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpenedInBackground(intent);

        //Here is data you sent
        Log.i("", intent.getExtras().getString( "com.parse.Data" ));

        Intent i = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
    }
}
```

All works fine
But if I close the app , and then sending a push notification-> the app crashes with following logs:

```
11-09 21:13:11.621: E/com.parse.PushService(23087): The Parse push service cannot start because Parse.initialize has not yet been called. If you call Parse.initialize from an Activity's onCreate, that call should instead be in the Application.onCreate. Be sure your Application class is registered in your AndroidManifest.xml with the android:name property of your <application> tag.
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.parse.PushService@4203adb0 with Intent { act=com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE flg=0x10 pkg=com.myparse.app cmp=com.myparse.app/com.parse.PushService (has extras) }: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2782)
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: applicationContext is null. You must call Parse.initialize(context, applicationId, clientKey) before using the Parse library.
11-09 21:13:11.626: E/AndroidRuntime(23087):    at com.parse.Parse.checkContext(Parse.java:606)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I experienced the same problem, and solved it by adding 
**android:name=".MyApplication"** to the application tag in the Android manifest, and then creating a new class that looks like this:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate() { 
         Parse.initialize(getApplicationContext(), myAppId, myClientKey);
    }
}
```

Previously I'd put the Parse initialisation call in the onCreate() method of my main Activity, but as the error message you posted suggests, the subtleties of the Android lifecycle mean you can't do that.