# How should I add application name in manifest (android)

Tags: android, manifest

How can I add the application name in manifest (android) ?

```
 <application
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/chair"
        android:label="@string/app_name"

        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
```

Comment: Do you have an application class?

Comment: In place of .MainActivity in  android:name=".MainActivity" place your application name.

Comment: Have you done this....http://stackoverflow.com/a/27196521/1479511........If yes, then add the application name in place of .MainActivity inside application tag

Comment: I'm really confused, my application name is "asan" and when i put it, it's not accept...

Comment: `android:label="asan"`

Comment: I do that, I was restart  after that, but android didn't accept it.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna add extra activity files that are use for navigation purpose then after the activity tag that comes bydefault add extra new tag called activity.

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:allowBackup="true">
<activity android:label="@string/app_name"
android:name="com.example.travel.MainActivity">
<intent-filter>

<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>

</intent-filter>

</activity>

<activity android:name="SecondActivity"/>

<activity android:name="ThirdActivity"/>

 </application>
```

Comment: thank you, I just want to add my application name to my manifest. this link force me to add ApplicationName. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831663/app-crashes-if-app-is-closed-using-push-service-parse-com)

Comment: Your applicatin name will be added  using Android:label="@string/app_name"

Comment: just check out your string file. in that one tag will be there called app_name. there you find your app name. or else just post your string file here.

Comment: @Tara I don't think OP needs android:label. He just needs to give the application class name in manifest, I guess.

Comment: @DroidWormNarendra he gave application class name. and asked to add application name. that will be in string file. s he just needs to check that.

Comment: @Tara have you checked the link, that OP suggested?

Comment: yes dear @DroidWormNarendra .It's really hurrble for me to add application name to manifest...

Comment: @user1794863 What do you find `hurrble`? It is the supposed way to do that. I always do that, and it works pretty fine.

Comment: @user1794863 remove  android:name=".MainActivity" from your application tag. it should only be in activity tag.

Comment: I was make an sample for test, [check this link](http://www.yekvip.com/testtt.rar)

Comment: <string name="app_name">testtt</string> edit testtt to your app name. i-e asan

Comment: and make changes in your manifest file from <android:name="testtt"> to android:name="@string/app_name

Comment: Dear @Tara in this sample i show you, app_name and everything is "testtt" but it's didn't work..

Comment: then just remove android:name=".MainActivity from your application tag. then it works. in manifest file your are declaring two times your class/Activity name

Comment: thank you, but in this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831663/app-crashes-if-app-is-closed-using-push-service-parse-com/27196521#27196521](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26831663/app-crashes-if-app-is-closed-using-push-service-parse-com/27196521#27196521) ,he forced me to use  android:name...

Comment: then he has created a new class too... just remove it and test it.

Comment: dear @Tara, thank you . I think the problem is about new class, what you said. thank you [link](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/PushTutorial/blob/master/Android/AndroidManifest.xml)